# Mutually dependent structures in sml

Tags: sml

It is possible to define mutually dependent datatypes in `sml` via the `and` keyword. Now I have two structures that reference each other and it seems the errors I see are because it's mutually recursive but I don't see a way to add `and` in such a way that this might work.

Example:

```
structure Machine = struct 
  structure F = Frame
  ...
end

structure Frame = struct
  ...
  reference to Machine.wordsize
end
```

Can this be made to work or is the design incompatible with `sml`? I am porting code from `Ocaml` and apparently this works there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible. I have found the answer [here](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/FAQ/faq.txt).

The answer to the second question in section 1.2.0, `Q: [Allyn Dimock] Recursive modules`

> Many people have asked for a way of defining mutually recursive
>   structures (e.g. mutually recursive abstract syntax of commands and
>   expressions, each in its own module).  This could be done, though the
>   set of mutually recursive modules would almost certainly have to be
>   compiled as a single compilation unit, so they would not be truly
>   "separate" modules.  However, having recursive definitions involving
>   functor applications appears much more difficult, and mutually
>   recursive functors would be even more mind-boggling.

Answer (score 9):

In Standard ML, two structures can't refer to each other directly. In fact, even one structure can't refer to itself directly; in something like `structure S = struct ... end`, any occurrence of the structure identifier `S` inside the `...` would have to refer to some previously-defined structure `S`, rather than to the one currently being defined. (This is because of inference rules 57 and 61 on page 32 of the *Definition*, which define how structure declarations and structure bindings are elaborated. In order for this elaboration to be recursive, the resulting structure environment *SE* would have to appear on the left-hand side of the hypothesis in one of these rules.) The syntax does allow structure bindings to be combined using `and` (in the rule for *strbind* on page 13 of the *Definition*), but its effect is the opposite of what you want: in something like `structure S = struct ... end and T = struct ... end`, you can't even have `T` refer to `S` (because both bindings are elaborated in the same basis, meaning that the result of binding `S` is not available inside the binding of `T`).

However, it is probably possible to accomplish what you want; you'll just have to come at it a bit more obliquely. For example, one approach is to put both declarations inside a `local` declaration, with all of the important bits declared in the top part:

```
local
  ... (* everything needed for both Frame and Machine *) ...
in
  structure Frame = struct ... end
  structure Machine = struct ... end
end
```

Another approach is to declare the structures somewhat piecemeal, with successive refinements:

```
structure Machine = struct ... wordsize ... end
structure Frame = struct ... M.wordsize ... end
structure Machine = struct open Machine ... end
```

(Here the `Machine` referred to inside the last declaration is that one that was bound in the first declaration.) This sort of successive refinement is sometimes used to "seal" a structure after creating friends:

```
structure Foo = struct ... end
... (* code that has full access to the guts of Foo *) ...
structure Foo = Foo : sig ... end
... (* code that only sees what's exposed in the signature *) ...
```